# Mobile: Store images dowloaded from server in db (Akavache) or as file?

Tags: mobile, azure-blob-storage, akavache

When I use Azure Storage and its Mobile SDK, blobs are stored as files on the device.

Whereas when I read about Akavache it's say it's fast to store and access blobs.

So if I display a list of images, is it faster to them from akavache in one transaction or to get them from the file system ?

Answer (score 0):

While I have been using Akavache to store data for a while, I really don't know how use it with files or imagens.

But I know is that when someone talks about caching and restoring images on mobile the most common solution is https://github.com/daniel-luberda/FFImageLoading

Take a look, it may be a better option.

Comment: I know about that library. I don't like it . But that's my personal opinion.